# Use "accesskey" attribute of apex:commandbutton in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, commandbutton

I am trying to implement a functionality that would allow users to invoke controller method by pressing "enter" key also. I know "accesskey" attribute of apex:commandbutton can be used to perform such function. However, i cannot find proper documentation for the same. Can anyone please cite an example of how to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2):

The accesskey attribute is an HTML attribute not specific to Visualforce. It's a keyboard accessibility feature used to jump to a particular part of a web page via the keyboard. In HTML it works like this:

```
<a href="index.html" accesskey="h">Home</a>
<input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Submit" />
```

In this case, depending on the browser and operating system, a user could press ALT-H / ALT-S(for Chrome on Windows) and it would execute the link/button as though the user clicked on it. Some browsers, including earlier versions of Internet Explorer, also require you to press Enter but most don't.

The accesskey on apex:commandbutton just adds the attribute to the HTML element it renders, it doesn't do anything fancy with it. If you try the following in a Visualforce page with the appropriate accesskey combination for your browser you'll see each button get focus briefly and the page will refresh, as though you clicked on the button.

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:form>
    <apex:commandbutton accesskey="s" value="S" />
    <apex:commandbutton accesskey="h" value="H" />
  </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

AFAIK there is no way to set the accesskey to be the Enter key. They aren't particularly widely used any more since (1) they often conflict with keyboard shortcuts used by assistive technologies, and (2) they're not easily discoverable by users.

According to [another post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/41860/2730), Visualforce defaults to the first button in the page when you click Enter, which is similar to the way most HTML forms work (usually Enter submits the form if focus is not on another element that can handle it, e.g. a link).

More information on accesskey:

- [Web Accessibility Initiative spec for accesskey on input buttons](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-ACCESSKEY-INPUT.html)
- [Wikipedia entry on accesskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) (including browser support matrix)
- [Standard Access Keys](http://www.standardaccesskeys.com/SAK2014/) - an attempt at standardizing on common keyboard shortcuts

Comment: - That's a very helpful description and I really appreciate the time you have taken to explain me. I am looking for such functionality because i read somewhere that this is possible to achieve.